# Internal server error- date malformed

Tags: javascript, java, backbone.js

I am working with backbone js and oracle DB. The application date in my dump is 15/04/16 , I've created a form using js when I click on submit I am getting the following error.

```
        Top of stack : 
    org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:224)

 **** Bottom of stack :     
    org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseLocalDateTime(DateTimeFormatter.java:900)
        **** Exception is Invalid format: "15/04/2016" is malformed at "/04/2016"
        **** Stack trace is
```

Comment: It must be expecting the date to be in USA format, mm/dd/yy rather than dd/mm/yy, and 15 is not a valid month.

Comment: Please include a [mcve].

Comment: I got it fixed , in the respective .JS file i didn't add render for on of the date fields of the page

Answer (score 0):

the date format is not valid. Joda-Time API is used by default US locale format in your JVM.
You have to parse the input date.
You can use this part of code

```
        //Input date
    String input = "15/04/16";
    //Cast input to Joda datime
    DateTime dt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yy").parseDateTime(input);
    //Use toString method to take a format String needed
    String output = dt.toString(FORMAT_DATE);
    //output date
    System.out.println(output);// it shoud be 04/15/2016
```

Comment: FORMAT_DATE should be replaced by "MM/dd/yyyy"